# void android.view.View.setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList) Error in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtInputLayDateOfBirth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDateOfBirth"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drop_down"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/dob"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

When I following statement it gives error

```
mDateOfBirthTextInputLayout.setError(error.getCollatedErrorMessage(mContext));
```

It was working fine in Android 4.4 but gives error in Android 5.1

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.sample, PID: 1824
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop.setBackgroundTintList(ViewCompatLollipop.java:78)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LollipopViewCompatImpl.setBackgroundTintList(ViewCompat.java:1602)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(ViewCompat.java:2893)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateEditTextBackground(TextInputLayout.java:544)
at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:445)
at com.example.sample.ui.CompleteProfileFragment$RegistrationController.onValidationFailed(CompleteProfileFragment.java:390)
at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.triggerValidationListenerCallback(Validator.java:721)
at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validateFieldsWithCallbackTill(Validator.java:697)
at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validateUnorderedFieldsWithCallbackTill(Validator.java:679)
at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validate(Validator.java:334)
at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validate(Validator.java:295)
```

What could be the error?. No error is appearing when the `EditText` is inside the `TextInputLayout`. But gives error in the case when a `TextView` is placed inside it.